# What is the meaning of "Twice yet, carle, I'll come to Spain!"

Tags: etymology, idioms, middle-english

The phrase "Twice yet, carle, I'll come to Spain!" occurs in the obscure fairy tale [Molly Whuppie](http://sarahbethdurst.blogspot.com/2006/11/obscure-fairy-tale-molly-whuppie.html?m=1) ([more original version?](http://www.kayfabe.com/?p=1724)) after a princess tricks a giant by stealing his sword. Contextually:

> "Woe worth you, Molly Whuppie! never you come again."
>
> "Twice yet, carle," quoth she, "I'll come to Spain."

This is the second time the giant has been tricked, which I believe may link to "twice." It's an idiom, though, so I can't be certain. What is Molly trying to communicate, and where does this idiom come from?

Edit: I think "twice yet" is a reference to the fact that she'll show up twice more - though I have no idea how she would know this.

Comment: Have a read of [Maol A Chliobain](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/celt/pt1/pt121.htm).

Comment: @mplungjan I'm curious why it was listen NSFW?

Comment: I don-t know, My office marked it ADULT so I just added the tag

Comment: Might have marked it NSFW so more people would read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quoting the epic poem The Song Of Roland about Charlemagne going into Spain to fight the Muslims

Answer (score 2):

Standard fairy tale promise. "I'll be baaack"

Many fairy tales have things come in three.

She knows that the king will ask something impossible for each of his sons and there are three of them.

Comment: Any particular reason for the use of Spain?

Comment: Not that I can find. Perhaps it was not Spain when it was first told and misheard... or perhaps the Giant used to live in Spain

Comment: *Twice yet* = *Twice more*. The next time she comes she says 'Once yet...'; and after the final visit she says 'Never more, carle,' quoth she, 'will I come again to Spain.'

Answer (score 0):

*Carle* is a form of *churl*,  a mildly insulting form of address, perhaps similar to 'My lad'.  And *yet* meaning 'in the future' isn't all that uncommon: "The car's broken down and the railway's on strike, but don't worry, boss, I'll get to work yet!"